# Can't play aac audio format on Ipad simulator IOS 6

Tags: ios6

I don't play .aac audio format on iPad simulator IOS6. On OS X is Okay, play good.
this is my code:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"/Users/macmini/Desktop/MyAudio.aac"];   
NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];    
AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];    
[audio play];
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your code...

You can't play the audio without set your volume
You can get crash your app

```
[audio prepareToPlay];
audio.volume = 1.0;
```